# Symfony - form - many to many relation - collection type

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony

Here is the situation:

I have an entity Property

```
class Property
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PropertyEquipment", inversedBy="properties")
     */
    protected $propertyEquipments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->propertyEquipments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function addPropertyEquipment(\AppBundle\Entity\PropertyEquipment $propertyEquipment)
    {
        $this->propertyEquipments[] = $propertyEquipment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePropertyEquipment(\AppBundle\Entity\PropertyEquipment $propertyEquipment)
    {
        $this->propertyEquipments->removeElement($propertyEquipment);
    }

    public function getPropertyEquipments()
    {
        return $this->propertyEquipments;
    }
}
```

And the entity PropertyEquipment:

```
class PropertyEquipment
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Property", mappedBy="propertyEquipments")
     */
    protected $properties;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    protected $equipmentName;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->properties = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEquipmentName()
    {
        return $this->equipmentName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $equipmentName
     */
    public function setEquipmentName($equipmentName)
    {
        $this->equipmentName = $equipmentName;
    }

    public function addProperty(Property $property)
    {
        $this->properties[] = $property;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProperty(Property $property)
    {
        $this->properties->removeElement($property);
    }

    public function getProperties()
    {
        return $this->properties;
    }
}
```

The form PropertyCreation

```
class PropertyCreation extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            //with this I see the values coming from DB in the template
            ->add("propertyEquipments", PropertyEquipmentCreation::class)

            //with this it's empty :/
            /*->add("propertyEquipments", CollectionType::class, array(
                "entry_type" => PropertyEquipmentCreation::class,
            ))*/
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Property::class
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is the form PropertyEquipmentCreation:

```
class PropertyEquipmentCreation extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder      
            ->add('propertyEquipment', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PropertyEquipment',
                'choice_label' => 'equipmentName',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => PropertyEquipment::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the controller

```
public function createPropertyAction(Request $request)
{
    $property = new Property();

    $form = $this->createForm(PropertyCreation::class, $property);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($property);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }
    return $this->render('form/owner_create_property.html.twig', ["form" => $form->createView()]);
}
```

My error:

`Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\Property#$propertyEquipments", got "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" instead.`

Must I transform these  with something like `class PropertyEquipmentTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface`?

Comment: without `CollectionType` how you are handling the view? how you are storing the field in `data-prototype` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `getParent()` function in `PropertyEquipmentCreation` and inherit from `EntityType::class` then put all your field configs in the `configureOptions()` function (remove the `buildForm` function) and it should work.

You are having this problem because it is a `compound form` in your implementation and no `simple form` and symfony is unable to resolve which field created inside the subform needs to be used as source for the entity field

Answer (score 1):

First !

Big thanks to Nickolaus !

Here is the solution (PropertyEquipmentCreation):

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class PropertyEquipmentCreation extends AbstractType
{

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PropertyEquipment',
        'choice_label' => 'equipmentName',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ]);
}

public function getParent()
{
    return EntityType::class;
}
}
```

And for (PropertyCreation)

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Form;


use AppBundle\Form\Type\PropertyEquipmentCreation;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PropertyCreation extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add("propertyEquipments", PropertyEquipmentCreation::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Property::class
    ));
}
}
```

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try using Doctrine ArrayCollection instead of ArrayCollections:

```
$this->propertyEquipments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

This should work!

Comment: Hi Manuel :) I will try :)

Comment: Hi Manuel,

That's what I use...

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\Property#$propertyEquipments", got "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" instead.

But thx :)

Comment: Hmm you are importing it, but I dont think you are using in the constructor, have you replaced new ArrayCollection(); to new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); ?

Comment: I found the solution... I will post that in a few minutes :)