# Symfony 3.4 form EntityType selected value is empty

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I have an issue with Symfony 3.4 EntityType.

**CategoryType.php**

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('spec', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => SpecificationType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => false,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Category::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

**SpecificationType.php**

```
class SpecificationType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Specification::class,
            'label' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Specification::class,
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'specification';
    }
}
```

Form renders as expected: Title as Text field, and 2 select elements. But problem is rendered select element does not select selected value.

**form.html.twig**

```
{{ form_widget(form.title) }}
{{ form_widget(form.spec) }}
```

**Result**
[image]

**Expected result**
[image]

When in `SpecificationType.php` `EntityType::class` is replaced with `TextField:class` now form renders not 2 select elements bus 2 text inputs (expected behaviour) and values assigned are correct:
[image]

I started digging how these select elements are rendered in first place, and found that this block `{%- block choice_widget_options -%}` is responsible for rendering select element.

Inside this block is peace of code:

```
<option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice.attr %}{% with { attr: choice.attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}</option>
```

Exactly this condition: `{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}` is responsible for adding `selected` attribute to option. But `value` in `selectedchoice(value)` extension is somehow empty, that's why he is not marking option as selected.

Maybe anyone knows, how to solve this issue?

**UPDATED**

`spec` property is defined like this:

**CategoryEntity.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Specification", inversedBy="categoryList")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="category_specification")
 */
private $spec;
```

Comment: Can you please show how `spec` property is defined in `Category` entity?

Comment: @Djengobarm please see updated section.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39766828/2950517).

As @Nickolaus wrote:

`[..] You are having this problem because it is a compound form in your implementation and no simple form and symfony is unable to resolve which field created inside the subform needs to be used as source for the entity field`

So solution is:

Refactor `SpecificationType.php` like this:

```
class SpecificationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => Specification::class,
            'label' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'specification';
    }
}
```

Use `getParent()` method, move all field configs to `configureOptions` and remove `buildForm()` method.

Finally.. so many hours wasted..